# What is the Pragmatic Marketing Framework, and how do I go about learning it in the quickest time possible?

Tags: pmi-framework

I've seen several references to the PMF, and I'm wondering what it is, and where I can find good reference material to do a quick, deep, dive?

Comment: There should be some sort of Urban Dictionary that helps a guy play acronym bingo.  To pass time in meetings that involve new acronyms, I make up my own acronyms. I find that staying appropriately cynical helps to avoid wasting a lot of time with half-baked flavor-of-the-month ideas.  When I've seen references to PMF, I think the "P" stood for "Poor." As in, "So, you are the PMF who has to learn about the Pragmatic Marketing Framework?" Instead of M.F., many would substitute another acronym, like S.O.B.  As in, "So, you are the PSOB who has to learn about the Pragmatic Marketing Framework?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pragmatic Marketing Framework is fully detailed at [this site](http://www.pragmaticmarketing.com/pragmatic-marketing-framework).

The framework appears to be a vendor-specific model used by the Pragmatic Marketing company as the shared basis for many of their seminars and training services. According to one source, over 60,000 people have been trained using the framework... about the same as official Certified Scrum Master course completions as of year or two ago. This implies it probably has significant value as a shared language and as a reasonable taxonomy/ontology for product development and marketing topics.

As for a jump start, other than attending the official training, there appears to be quite a few articles available around the framework located [here](http://www.pragmaticmarketing.com/resources/articles).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to http://www.pragmaticmarketing.com/about-us/framework  to learn more.  It basically provides a breakdown of marketing tasks into steps so that organizations take a broader approach, incorporating metrics and planning into marketing (imagine that).

Comment: Hey Monique, would you be able to expand on this to bring in some of the main ideas into this post via an [edit]?